# Como enviar um Value de um botão que contem uma imagem?

Tags: javascript, css, imagem, javascript-eventos, button

Estou com um problema, preciso enviar um value através do botão, porém quando adicionei a imagem nele, ele parou de enviar o `target.value` e está enviando `undefined`. Alguém teria uma alternativa?

```
` <tbody>
          { arraySmartphones.map(({ Brand, Model, Code, Color, Price}, index) =>
            <tr>
              <td data-label="Codigo">{Code}</td>
              <td data-label="Modelo">{Model}</td>
              <td data-label="Preço">R$ {Price}</td>
              <td data-label="Marca">{Brand}</td>
              <td data-label="Cor">{Color}</td>
              <div className="buttons">
              <button className="btn-edit"type="button" value={Code} onClick={editSmartphone}>
                <img className="edit" alt="Editar Item" src={ Edit }/>
              </button>              
              
              <button className="btn-trash" type="button" value={index} onClick={deleteSmartphone}>
                <img className="trash" alt="Lixeira" src={ Trash }/>
              </button>               
             
              </div>
            </tr>
          )} 
          </tbody>`
```

Como podem ver o meu Botão Edit recebe um value=Code que eu envio para uma função, e o meu Botão Trash recebe o index que eu uso para deletar o objeto pelo value dele.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o erro acontece porque você está tentando pegar o `value` a partir do `event.target` então se você clicar na imagem dentro do botão, ele vai pegar o `value` da imagem e não do botão.

Uma solução é você verificar se a tag clicada foi a `img`, nesse caso você captura o `parentNode` que é a tag `button`, exemplo...

```js
let button = document.querySelector("button");

button.onclick = function(event) {
    let result = (event.target.tagName === "BUTTON") ? event.target.value : event.target.parentNode.value;
  
    console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<button value="teste">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
</button>
```

Comment: Agradecido de mais amigo, deu super certo, não conhecia esse método de parentNode.